# How to get bash ssh server started from psexec or user-logon script in windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, psexec, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a W10 machine with bash set up. If I open a cmd window and type `bash -i` I can get to a bash shell no problem. However, if I enter the W10 machine using psexec and the same user and type `bash -i`, everything just hangs.

I know I can and do use an Ubuntu ssh server to get in, but I can only do that if the Ubuntu ssh server is running. It only seems to run if there is at least one bash session active. I thought I could use the psexec entry as a backup and start the Ubuntu ssh server or do anything else, but from the psexec cmd window, I cannot get to bash. When I type `bash -i` everything hangs and I need to close the cmd window on the remote machine.

The same problem occurs if I use a windows ssh server. I can get to a cmd window, but everything hangs if I type `bash -i`.

I also tried the Windows task scheduler to try to start the Ubuntu ssh server at a user login, but that also just hangs.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.